# Override and change ionic menu style for a specific page

Tags: ionic-view

My `ion-menu` is embedded in `nav-bar`. I am using `ionic` material design from the following link.

http://ionicmaterial.com/

The menu is coming whenever I slide left. I don't need this functionality in one page. how can I override the sliding property?